# Android application that can concatenate two videos without re-encoding the videos

Tags: android, video-editing, video-recording, lossless

I'm looking for an Android application that can concatenate two videos without re-encoding the videos. The two videos have the exact same format and encoding. On Linux, Windows or macOS, I would use ffmpeg. Any license or price is fine. I tried YouCut but I suspect it may perform some re-encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run ffmpeg also on Android by utilizing environment like [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=pl&gl=US). Install it with a command like:

```
pkg install -y ffmpeg
```

and grant it access to files.

Rooting may or not be required depending on Android version and specific OS.